# How to save image created with 'pandas.DataFrame.plot'?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

When trying to save plot image created with 'pandas.DataFrame.plot' from ' pandas.core.series.Series' object :

```
%matplotlib inline
type(class_counts) # pandas.core.series.Series
class_counts.plot(kind='bar',  figsize=(20, 16), fontsize=26)
```

Like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.savefig('figure_1.pdf', dpi=300)
```

results in empty pdf file. How to save image created with 'pandas.DataFrame.plot'?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Try this :

```
fig = class_counts.plot(kind='bar',  
        figsize=(20, 16), fontsize=26).get_figure()

fig.savefig('test.pdf')
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked with ".boxplot" as well.